# Invalid column data1 error while retrieving contact number using Loader

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    private static final String TAG = "ContentProviderDemo";

    private int recentOpPerfomed;

    private final int LOAD_CONTACTS=1;
    private final int WRITE_CONTACTS=2;
    private final int UPDATE_CONTACTS=3;
    private final int DELETE_CONTACTS=4;





    private boolean firstTimeLoaded=false;

    private TextView textViewQueryResult;
    private Button buttonLoadData, buttonAddContact,buttonRemoveContact,buttonUpdateContact, buttonPhotoTagActivity;

    private ContentResolver contentResolver;

    private EditText editTextContactName;
    private CursorLoader mContactsLoader;

    private String[] mColumnProjection = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER}
    ;

    private String mSelectionCluse = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " = ?";

    private String[] mSelectionArguments = new String[]{"Ajay"};

    private String mOrderBy = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewQueryResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewQueryResult);

        editTextContactName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextContactName);

        buttonLoadData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadData);

        buttonAddContact=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAddContact);
        buttonRemoveContact=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRemoveContact);
        buttonUpdateContact=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdateContact);

        buttonPhotoTagActivity=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPhotoTagActivity);



        buttonLoadData.setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonAddContact.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonRemoveContact.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUpdateContact.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonPhotoTagActivity.setOnClickListener(this);

        contentResolver=getContentResolver();

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        if(i==1){
            return  new CursorLoader(this,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,mColumnProjection, null,null,null);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0){
            StringBuilder stringBuilderQueryResult=new StringBuilder("");
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){

                if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
                {
                    // Query phone here. Covered next
                    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "
                                    + ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, null, null);
                    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        Log.i("Number", phoneNumber);
                        stringBuilderQueryResult.append(cursor.getString(0)+" , "+cursor.getString(1)+
                                " , "+cursor.getString(2)+" , "+phoneNumber+"\n");
                    }
                    phones.close();
                }
            }
            textViewQueryResult.setText(stringBuilderQueryResult.toString());
        }else{
            textViewQueryResult.setText("No Contacts in device");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonLoadData:loadContacts();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonAddContact: addContact();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonRemoveContact:deleteContact();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonUpdateContact: modifyCotact();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonPhotoTagActivity: startPhotoTagActivity();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void startPhotoTagActivity(){
        startActivity(new Intent(this,PhotoTaggingActivity.class));
    }



    private void insertContacts(){

        String newName=editTextContactName.getText().toString();
        if(newName!=null && !newName.equals("") && newName.length()!=0){
            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> cops=new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

            cops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,"accountname@gmail.com")
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "com.google")
                    .build());
            cops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, editTextContactName.getText().toString())
                    .build());

            try{
                getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY,cops);
            }catch (Exception exception){
                Log.i(TAG,exception.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(this,exception.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void addContact() {
        recentOpPerfomed=WRITE_CONTACTS;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            insertContacts();
        } else {
            requestRunTimePermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS},MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_CONTACTS);
        }
    }


    private void updateContact(){

        String [] updateValue=editTextContactName.getText().toString().split(" ");
        ContentProviderResult[] result=null;

        String targetString=null;
        String newString=null;
        if(updateValue.length==2){
            targetString=updateValue[0];
            newString=updateValue[1];
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if(newString!=null && !newString.equals("") && newString.length()!=0)
                {
                    String where= ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID + " = ? ";
                    String [] params= new String[] {targetString};
                    ContentResolver contentResolver=getContentResolver();
                    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(ContactsContract.RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,newString);
                    // UPDATE <table_name> SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2 where column3 = selection_value
                    contentResolver.update(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,contentValues, where,params);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void modifyCotact(){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            updateContact();
        } else {
            requestRunTimePermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_CONTACTS);
        }
    }

    private void removeContacts(){
        recentOpPerfomed=DELETE_CONTACTS;
        String newName=editTextContactName.getText().toString();
        if(newName!=null && !newName.equals("") && newName.length()!=0){
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //display_name = '<entered_value>'
                String whereClause=ContactsContract.RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY+ " = '"+editTextContactName.getText().toString()+"'";
                //DELETE FROM <table_name> where column1 = selection_value
                getContentResolver().delete(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,whereClause,null);
            }
        }

    }

    private void deleteContact(){
        recentOpPerfomed=DELETE_CONTACTS;
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            removeContacts();
        }else{
            requestRunTimePermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_CONTACTS);
        }
    }


    private void loadContacts() {
        recentOpPerfomed=LOAD_CONTACTS;
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Log.i(TAG,"Permisssion is granted");
            if (firstTimeLoaded == false) {
                getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
                firstTimeLoaded = true;
            } else {
                getLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, null, this);
            }
        }else{
            requestRunTimePermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(final int requestCode, @NonNull final String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(permissions.length==1){
            if(requestCode==MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS || requestCode==MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_CONTACTS && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                switch (recentOpPerfomed){
                    case WRITE_CONTACTS: addContact();loadContacts();break;
                    case DELETE_CONTACTS: deleteContact();loadContacts();break;
                    case  UPDATE_CONTACTS: modifyCotact();loadContacts();break;
                    case LOAD_CONTACTS:loadContacts();
                    default: break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Wasted almost an day on this. Trying to get Phone Number from Contacts APP.
I am trying to retrieve all contacts phone number using Loader. There is no proper explanation in Logcat where i am going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I keep getting saying Invalid column data1,but what is Invalid column data1?

Comment: Hi, could you also add the relevant portions of the stack trace to the question.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255434/logcat-says-invalid-column-data1