# voice command app, to make a call a contact from the contact list

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I want to develop a voice command app, which can take commands from user and perform it accordingly. Till now i have successfully created "open app" functionality in it, now I want to implement "call  " command in it. I have been researching fact from a really long time but haven't come up with any proper solution. i m able to make calls to a spoken number like on dial pad but not any saved contacts. Is there any contact manager in android like packagemanager which can help me to traverse my contact list or something else that can help.
Please if anyone have any information, please share it to me.
Thanking you ...

Comment: You are referring to Contacts Provider. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html) link. Possible [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218845/how-to-get-contacts-phone-number-in-android)

Comment: Yes, also have a look at this developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.htm